# Cypress Testing - cy.exec timing out when running a script that works fine from the terminal

Tags: command-line-interface, cypress

I'm writing cypress tests for an application that tracks candidates through a hiring process.  A candidate will go through several state changes as they move through the process, so I set up a script to reset the test candidate in the database.  I plan to run the script using cy.exec in a before() block at the beginning of my tests, so that the candidate will always be in the correct state to start the hiring process.  Here is the function that gets run:

```
const { Candidate } = require("../models/Candidate");
const lever = require("../services/lever.js");
const logger = require("../utils/logger");

const funcs = {
  resetCandidates: async () => {
    await Candidate.update(
      { id: "72224076-49c3-4c3b-b449-25aa2a67b426" },
      { $SET: { referencesCompleted: false } }
    );
    const candidate = await Candidate.get(
      "2b2ed420-5ce7-4e76-817f-a6d309a438a1"
    );
    const { authorizationDocumentsId, ...updatedBackgroundCheck } =
      candidate.backgroundCheck;
    await Candidate.update(
      { id: "2b2ed420-5ce7-4e76-817f-a6d309a438a1" },
      {
        $REMOVE: ["offerLetterId"],
        $SET: {
          congratulationsModalShown: false,
          offerLetterSigned: false,
          backgroundCheck: {
            ...updatedBackgroundCheck,
            authorizationSigned: false,
          },
        },
      }
    );
    const leverCandidate = await lever.getOpportunitiesByContactPhoneNumber(
      candidate.leverData.phone
    );
    await lever.updateStageByName(leverCandidate[0].id, "offer-written");
    logger.info("Test Candidates Reset");
  },
};

module.exports = {
  funcs,
  handler: funcs.resetCandidates,
};
```

And this is the script in package.json: `"test-candidate-reset": "sls invoke -f testCandidateReset -s dev"`

If I run this script from the command line, it works perfectly every time and usually takes about 5-10 seconds.  But when I run it inside my Cypress tests, like this: `cy.exec("cd ../candidate-services && npm run test-candidate-reset")` it always times out after 60 seconds.  I know that cy.exec runs the command from the project root directory, so I've tried running the script with that exact same command from the root directory in the terminal and it works there, just not when Cypress tries to run it.  Every time I run the script manually, I can see the server logs when it runs, but when I run it with cy.exec, it doesn't seem to run at all and no new logs are created.  If anyone has any ideas for why this might be happening, I'd really appreciate the help.

Comment: What's the exact error that you receive from Cypress?

Comment: it's the usual timeout error, `cy.exec('cd ../candidate-services && npm run test-candidate-reset') timed out after waiting 60000ms.`

Comment: Did you eventually find out what was wrong?

Comment: No I did not.  I set up a workaround by writing a script that would run the desired script, and then launch cypress.